# Problem on filters

Tags: set-theory, filters

$\mathcal{F}$ is filter on $\mathcal{I}$, but not ultrafilter.

Prove that $\exists$$\mathcal{X, Y}\notin\mathcal{F}$ | $\forall\mathcal{Z}\in\mathcal{F}$ $\mathcal{X}\cap\mathcal{Z}\neq$ $\mathcal{Y}\cap\mathcal{Z}$

Thank you for your time.

Comment: You have not provided two key pieces of information: where did you encounter this problem (what course, what textbook), and what have you already tried?

Comment: In particular, it is important to define what $\mathcal{I}$ is supposed to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you know that a filter $\mathcal F$ on a set $I$ is an [ultrafilter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultrafilter) if and only if for any $X\subseteq I$ exactly one of the sets $X$ and $I\setminus X$ belongs to $\mathcal F$?

Using this fact we get that if $\mathcal F$ is **not** an ultrafilter, then there exists a set $X$ such that $X\notin\mathcal F$ and $I\setminus X\notin\mathcal F$. What could be a good candidate for $Y$ in such situation?

Comment: so, Y=I\X is answer to the problem?

Comment: That's what I was going for. Can you explain why $Y=I\setminus X$ fulfills the required condition? In the other words, if we choose $Y=I\setminus X$, how do we know that $X\cap Z\ne Y\cap Z$ for each non-empty set $Z\in\mathcal F$?

Comment: It's consequence of complement, I understand this. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

If you are familiar with filter germs this can be a solution:

Suppose the converse:
$$(\forall A,B\subseteq I:A,B\notin \mathcal F)(\exists C\in \mathcal F)(A\cap C=B\cap C)\quad\quad (1)$$

---

For each $A,B\subseteq I$ define:
$$A \sim  B \quad \leftrightarrow\quad (\exists C\in \mathcal F)(A\cap C=B\cap C)$$
$\sim$ is an equivalence relation on $\mathcal P(I)$. Each equivalence class of $\sim$ is called a **germ**.

Now your question is answered by these propositions:

- $\mathcal F$ is a germ.
- $\mathcal F$ is an ultrafilter iff there are exactly 2 germs.

---

By $(1)$:
$$(\forall A,B\subseteq I:A,B\notin \mathcal F)(A\sim B)$$
which shows there are exaclty  2 germs: $[\emptyset]$ and $\mathcal F=[X]$. So $\mathcal F$ is an ultrafilter. A contradiction.

Comment: Thank for your nice solution, but I didn't understand it at all.
Would not Y=I\X be a simpler solution?